Does Ising partition function determine the number of $k$-matchings mod $4$ for cubic graphs?
Let $G$ be a cubic graph. It's known that the Tutte polynomial $T_G$ of $G$ on the hyperbola $(x-1)(y-1)=2$ determines the Ising partition function of $G$ and vice versa.
A $k$-matching in a graph $G$ is a set of $k$ edges which are pairwise vertex-disjoint. Let $m_k(G)$ denote the number of $k$-matchings in the graph $G$.
Question: If $G$ and $H$ are two order-$n$ cubic graphs having the same Ising partition function, does $m_k(G)=m_k(H) \text{ mod } 4$ for $k=1 \dots \frac n2$?
Example: Take $G$ to be this graph and $H$ the Desargures graph. The Tutte polynomial of $G$ and $H$ agree on $(x-1)(y-1)=2$ and they have the same number of $k$-matchings for all $k \neq 14$; for $k=14$, $G$ has 1736 $k$-matchings and $H$ 1720. The difference between 1736 and 1720 is a multiple of 4.

The "Whitney twist" operation on graphs preserves the Tutte polynomial (because it preserves the graphic matroid). Do you know if your question has a positive answer if $G$ and $H$ are related by a twist?
